# Babel-cli is not compiling node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, node-modules

I cannot get babel-cli working. It crashes with error `Unexpected token 'export' in node_modules/...`.

I run it as `babel script.js -d dist`. While `babel-node script.js -i "[]"` works perfectly fine.

There is my `babel.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
}
```

Export and import syntax works perfectly fine in non `node_modules` scripts.

Comment: Is it for Webpack, do you use babel-loader?

Comment: @VictorShelepen, I am using babel-loader in some projects, and have had no problems. This problem only with babel cli, but it's already not actuall right now